# How do I skip rows with searchcursor based on an interger value

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpy, cursor

For example, if I have 100 records, and I want to sample 10% of the records. How do I tell the search cursor in arc10 to read the value of the 9th record, or every 10. I tried to do row[0 + count] and updated a count variable += 9 but it said I can't slice a row. Any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Do you want a random sample? If so check out Hawth's Tools: http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/rndsel.php

Answer (score 5):

You could avoid the counter variable by using enumerate and modulus operator:

```
import arcpy
f = r'C:\esri-extract-data-where\test_data\test_data.gdb\export_test_1'

cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(f)
for i,r in enumerate(cursor):
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print i,r
del cursor
```

or in arcpy 10.1+

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(f, field_names='*') as cursor:
    for i,r in enumerate(cursor):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print i,r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a counter to your loop, so before you do the read line set your counter +=1, then put your read line into an if statement psedo code ex.

```
counter = 0
for i in list:
    counter +=1
    if counter ==9:
        read
        counter=0
```

Comment: if I did counter == 9, wouldn't that only run the code after the "if" statement one time, and not on 19,29,39, etc ?

Comment: True, revised to correct that issue.

Comment: The revision doesn't seem to work either. It is running the code 1 time on the 9th record and then stops. Wouldn't I need to re-set the counter to 0 for the code to repeat?

Comment: Was a typo-revised.

Comment: Better yet, put the mod in the definition query for the search cursor. Why query all the data if you will then ignore 90% of it? arcpy.SearchCursor(f,"""MOD(OBJECTID, 10) = 0""", fields)